# ER to Relational mapping to Create statments

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I am making a .NET website which makes uses of a database to store information. It's a practice/experimental project not related to work or uni projects.

My question is to with mapping of the ER diagram to a RelationModel and then onto writing the actual create table statements.

following is my ER:
 http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/2405/climsyclipboardf.jpg

i'm confused about the part where an entity has ISA relation so it can be two things.

i know how i can for example map Business Account to Account by including all the attributes of Account into Business Account, but not sure if it makes sense when it comes to create statements.

for example, Account is either business or private account has payment of either CC or Direct Debit. How do i do this in create table statements?

Answer (score 0):

For business vs. private accounts, you can make the account type an attribute of the account by implementing it in a column.  Now the same thing can be said about CC and Direct Debit.  It really depends on how intricate you want to make this system.

Comment: i didn't want to do that because there's cases where a member can have both business and private account as well as a Credit Card and Debit Card on account. by making CC and Bank ISA relation to Payment i can have both. I have a logic in my head that i just can't translate to paper.